# How can I vectorize my function to speed up the operation on my dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, data-science

I have a dataframe (below, i.e, membership), one field (A) has some row with the value in a sorted manner. There is also a new field (new) which at the beginning of the process is a copy of the field `C`. What I would like to do is that, if the previous row in `A` is the same as the current row in `A`, and if either the current row of `new` or previous row of `new` is `1`, the assign 1 to the current `new`. In the end, at the lasts of the repeated values of `A`, `new` will be `1` or `0` depending on the conditions in the function and the previous values where `A` is repeated will have `new` to be `0`. I am able to accomplish that with the function below.

```
membership = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(dict([('A', ['20000000460', '20000000460', '20000000460','20000000460','20000000459','20000000461','20000000461','20000000462','20000000464','20000000464','20000000464','20000000464','20000000465','20000000465','20000000466']), ('B', [4,0, 5,0, 6,0,2,5,6,7,4,3,2,7,9]), ('C', [1,1,0,0,0,1,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,1])]))

def members(df, field):
df[field] = df.C
print(field)
for i in range(1, df.shape[0]):
    if (df.loc[i, 'A'] == df.loc[i-1, 'A']) and\
    (df.loc[i-1, field] == 1 or df.loc[i, field] == 1):
        df.loc[i, field] = 1
        df.loc[i-1, field] = 0
```

The results of this function on the dataframe is in this [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qnZWA.png)

The issue is that, I have a very large dataset and running this function on it is very slow. How can I improve the code to make it faster? I know if I am able to vectorize this function in pandas, the time will improve significantly. How can I vectorize this function?

Comment: To reference a value before or after the specific value, use ``df.A.shift(-1)`` or ``df.A.shift(1)``, respectively. I am note sure whether you can replace the whole loop because the if condition references a state which whill be changed if the condition is true.

Comment: I am curious.  Why in your results is where A equal to 2000000459 new is not set to 1 but is instead set to zero?  I would think that this is a new member right?

Comment: @ScottBoston, it is supposed to be zero since `C` from which I copied `new` from is zero.

Comment: @brimborium, I have tried that                                           
`membership['new'] = membership.C`
                                                                                            `membership['new'] = np.where((membership.A == membership.A.shift()) & ((membership.new == 1) |(membership.new.shift() == 1)), 1, membership.new)` but it does not work as expected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IIUC, Let me explain a little logic and see if this matches.

If in any group of A, a value of C is equal to 1, then assign to the last records in that group a value of 1 to column 'new'.

```
membership['new'] = membership.groupby('A')['C']\
                              .transform(lambda x: np.where(x.index == x.index[-1], 
                                                            x.max(), 0))
```

Output:

```
              A  B  C  new
0   20000000460  4  1    0
1   20000000460  0  1    0
2   20000000460  5  0    0
3   20000000460  0  0    1
4   20000000459  6  0    0
5   20000000461  0  1    0
6   20000000461  2  0    1
7   20000000462  5  1    1
8   20000000464  6  1    0
9   20000000464  7  1    0
10  20000000464  4  0    0
11  20000000464  3  0    1
12  20000000465  2  0    0
13  20000000465  7  0    0
14  20000000466  9  1    1
```

Comment: @K.Sante You're welcome. How did that work on your large dataset?

Comment: it took `0:26:16.190000` to go through 100K rows of data using the loop. It now takes `0:00:27.947000`. I was able to use your logic to resolve another for loop issue. Thanks again.